# MySQL Join 1-to-Many with FK is slow

Tags: mysql

I have a People and a Companies table. Each People record has a non-null FK Company_ID. I have about 130k companies, and 2.6M people records.

I have a full text index on people.name, which works great. This takes about 0.3 seconds:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `people`.`Name`
FROM mydb.`people`
WHERE match(`people`.`Name`) against('john')
```

Here are my table definitions and indices from a "show table create" run:

```
CREATE TABLE `companies` (
`Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Name` longtext,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
FULLTEXT KEY `companies_name_FT_IDX` (`Name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=129590 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `people` (
`Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Name` longtext,
`Company_Id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
KEY `IX_Company_Id` (`Company_Id`) USING HASH,
FULLTEXT KEY `people_name_FT_IDX` (`Name`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_People_Companies_Company_Id` FOREIGN KEY (`Company_Id`)       
REFERENCES `companies` (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2640085 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The problem is that a join with people and companies by ID takes over 16 seconds.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `companies`.`Id`, `companies`.`Name`, `people`.`Name`
FROM mydb.`companies`
INNER JOIN mydb.`people` ON mydb.`companies`.`Id` = mydb.`people`.`Company_Id` 
WHERE match(`people`.`Name`) against('john')
```

EDIT:
After looking at a whole bunch of stuff in Workbench, I saw the innodb buffer was maxing during query time. I traced that to be set in my.ini (Windows). It was set to 8M, I bumped it to 1G and restarted mysql. My queries run super fast now. Specifically: innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G

Is there a reason MySQL defaults are so small for resources? Is there some way I can use Workbench to set "recommended" values for my PC? It seems very likely there are more settings that I could bump up too just by browsing through the my.ini file.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `people LEFT JOIN companies` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to mention that, but left join instead of inner join seems to  have the same ~16 second query duration.

Comment: How about helping the optimizer a little bit?  Turn the `SELECT DISTINCT people.name FROM people WHERE match...` query into a subquery, and *then* join it with the `companies` table to get the extra fields you need.  So that would be `... FROM (subquery) AS s LEFT JOIN companies ON s.Company_Id = companies.id`

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT `companies`.`Id`, `companies`.`Name`, s.`Name`
FROM (
  select `people`.`Name`, `people`.`Id`, `people`.`Company_Id`
    from mydb.people
   WHERE match(`people`.`Name`) against('joe')
  ) AS s LEFT JOIN companies ON s.Company_Id = companies.id

Comment: right.  How did that one go?

Comment: That was definitely better - query was down to ~10.5 seconds from a solid 16 seconds.

Comment: If you leave everything as it is, but change `WHERE` to `AND` is it any faster?

Comment: I am surprised that it is still as much as ~10 seconds.  How many `people` rows match `'john'`?

Comment: Cancel that - still at 16 seconds. I used "joe" instead of "john". There are about 5k "joe" hits, and 15k "john" hits. Sorry for the bad test that I ran.

Comment: Good suggestion on the change 'where' to 'and', but no change in query speed. Still at 16 seconds.

Comment: How long does it take to do a simple query like `SELECT people.id, company.id FROM people LEFT JOIN company ON people.company_id = company.id WHERE people.id < 15000` ?

Comment: I ran that 3 times. It was never more than 0.6 seconds.

Comment: I need to go to sleep, so I can't be of any further help tonight.  I think that 0.6 seconds is very little, so the measurements may not be measuring the right thing.  You might be measuring time-to-first-row, in which case certain queries may have an unfair advantage, while time-to-last-row might be a better indicator of actual, usable performance.  With that in mind, you might want to repeat your tests, and see if you can learn anything new. (Hint: a `SELECT COUNT()` might yield interesting results.)  I will check again what's up tomorrow morning.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm using the Duration time values reported in the Output window of MySql workbench. I'm using a Mysql workbench and the Mysql instance is local to my computer too.

Answer (score 0):

Old versions of MySQL defaulted the critical setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to a pathetic 8M.  This *used to* lead to lots of questions on the various forums.  Then they upped the default to 128M; that got rid of most of the problems attributable to that setting.

If you have less than 4GB of RAM, that 1GB may be dangerously large.

If you are primarily using InnoDB, a good value is 70% if *available* RAM.  [*My blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory) on the topic.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I installed x64 MySQL 5.7 in Jan 2017 on Windows and it was still defaulting to 8M. My box has 12 GB RAM.